dictionary of lists of dictionaries not filtering
I tried the following:
positions = {
    'IBM': [
        {'ticker': 'IBM', 'start_date': '20240415', 'end_date': 99999999},
        {'ticker': 'IBM', 'start_date': '20240416', 'end_date': 00000000},
        {'ticker': 'IBM', 'start_date': '20240417', 'end_date': 99999999}],
    'MRK': [
        {'ticker': 'mmm', 'start_date': '20240415', 'end_date': 99999999},
        {'ticker': 'mmm', 'start_date': '20240416', 'end_date': 00000000},
        {'ticker': 'mmm', 'start_date': '20240417', 'end_date': 99999999}]}

new_pos = [position for position in positions.values() 
           if position[0].get('end_date') == 99999999]

print(new_pos)

and got back:
[[{'ticker': 'IBM', 'start_date': '20240415', 'end_date': 99999999}, 
  {'ticker': 'IBM', 'start_date': '20240416', 'end_date': 0}, 
  {'ticker': 'IBM', 'start_date': '20240417', 'end_date': 99999999}], 
 [{'ticker': 'mmm', 'start_date': '20240415', 'end_date': 99999999}, 
  {'ticker': 'mmm', 'start_date': '20240416', 'end_date': 0}, 
  {'ticker': 'mmm', 'start_date': '20240417', 'end_date': 99999999}]]

why is the if condition not working and why do we get back all records instead
of just the first record in the list with position[0]?
I think if the first dict of each list has end = 99999999 then we get back the entire list.  How do we just get back the dicts where end = 99999999?

positions. Values() should be position.values(). Python is case-sensitive.

You're returning the whole position list, not just position[0], in the list comprehension.

"why do we get back all records instead of just the first record in the list with position[0]?": Because you select position in the list comprehension, not position[0]

The filter is working fine, it's just not doing what you intended. What did you intend? Like, what's your desired output? It's not clear if you want a list of dicts or a list of lists of dicts, or something else.

Please add the desired result to the question. I suspect you need a nested filter.

To get back all dicts where the "end_date" key is 99999999, you'll need to add another level to the loop: iterate for record in position and select the record if record['end_date'] == 99999999

and this seems to do the trick:
new_pos = {key: [position for position in value
                 if position.get('end_date') == 99999999]
           for key, value in positions.items()}

we get back each key: list and then apply the if condition creating a new dict with key: list of correct values
